# Tortoise SVN does not ask for user/pass and fails

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I installed tortoiseSVN and was able to do a checkout of the dirs/files that are already in the repository (I don't need to authenticate for that)
When I try to commit changes I get the following error:

Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to CHECKOUT

I am never asked to enter my user/pass for authentication.

Tried googling it a bit, and found various mentions of this, but no definite answer.
I talked with the people in charge of the SVN server on our campus, and they claim that everything is OK on the server side...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe TortoiseSVN uses some saved authentication data that is no longer valid?

Try deleting any saved authentication data in TortoiseSVN's the settings dialog (under "Saved Data"), then retry committing.

Answer (score 9):

by my experience maybe:
1- you need to clear your authentication data in this way:
 right click >> setting >> saved data >> authentication data >> clear

2- you have to use "https://" protocol instead of "svn://" or "http://" when you want to checkout in some repository like sourceforge.net.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that **since version 1.8**, TortiseSVN prefers Kerberos (Active Directory) to password authentication. This means that **if the account you are logged in as doesn't have permissions to the SVN path, you will now get a `403 Forbidden` error**.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you talk with the repository over http or ssh.

You can then write the repository address this way: *protocol*://*username*@*machine-address*/*repository-dir*. This should force tortoise to log you in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your internet connection is not under a proxy. Otherwise, configure it at tortoise External Connection.

Also, cleaning the saved data settings (as mentioned by others users) is required

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether you are under proxy connection or not, if you are go to: 
         TortoiseSVN > Settings > Network 
Enable proxy, configure your proxy server information - server address and port should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you must remove the preceding spaces before the account/password settings in the config file(s) of the repository.

[alt text http://img365.imageshack.us/img365/7338/svnconfig.jpg](http://img365.imageshack.us/img365/7338/svnconfig.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Also, try replacing https:// with svn+ssh:// in the checkout.

That did the trick for me in a similar situation.

From: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup.html

Comment: This is only valid if the repository is served with `svn+ssh`. Most admins do not configure their repository for both HTTP and `svn+ssh`, so if he's already checked out a WC successfully it's a pretty safe bet that the URL is correct.